# Detect Mouse click location

Tags: javascript, html, events, mouseevent

What i am trying to achieve is make a DIV and display world map image on it or as a background.. & when user clicks some somewhere on the map, i catch the mouse-click location,

then i am some how going to translate the mouse's X,Y cords into longitude,latitude and then run an AJAX to display some data.

My problem is:

- How to get mouse click location with JavaScript
- How to translate the global click location into a DIV's relative X,Y coords of a layer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this example:

- [Click image and get coordinates with Javascript](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/)

Following posts may also help:

- [Get accurate position for a click on a linked image using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128643/get-accurate-position-for-a-click-on-a-linked-image-using-jquery)
- [Creating HTML Image Maps](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

In HTML you set onMouseMove event:

```
<div onMouseMove="getPositions();"
style="width:200px;height:100px"></div>
```

And javascript function:

```
function getPositions(ev) {
if (ev == null) { ev = window.event }
   _mouseX = ev.clientX;
   _mouseY = ev.clientY;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a reason to do it from scratch, I would recommend [Google Maps Api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/).

You'll notice that the [Map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) object has a click event to which you can bind a callback that receives a MouseEvent that contains lat/long coords. Check out [this example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-arguments.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler you can get it through the mouseEvent Args.

Excerpt from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404721.aspx -

```
function onMouseLeftButtonUp(sender, mouseEventArgs)
{
    // Return a Point object representing the x- and y-coordinates of the current mouse position
    // relative to the reference object.
    var pt = mouseEventArgs.getPosition(sender.findName("referenceObject"));

    // Display the current mouse position.
    sender.findName("Status").text = pt.x + " : " + pt.y;
}
```