# Rounding up to the nearest 0.05 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rounding

**Question**
Does anyone know of a way to round a float to the nearest 0.05 in JavaScript?

**Example**

```
BEFORE | AFTER
  2.51 | 2.55
  2.50 | 2.50
  2.56 | 2.60
```

**Current Code**

```
var _ceil = Math.ceil;
Math.ceil = function(number, decimals){
    if (arguments.length == 1)
    return _ceil(number);

    multiplier = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return _ceil(number * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

Then elsewhere... 
`return (Math.ceil((amount - 0.05), 1) + 0.05).toFixed(2);`

Which is resulting in...

```
BEFORE | AFTER
  2.51 | 2.55
  2.50 | 2.55
  2.56 | 2.65
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Multiply by 20, then divide by 20:

```
(Math.ceil(number*20)/20).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks very much. Are you able to explain *why* you need to do this?

Comment: although I'd  consider this change `Math.ceil(number*20 - 0.5)/20).toFixed(2)`

Comment: 1 = 20 * 0.05; you multiply by 20 so that rounding to the next integer and then dividing back by 20 is equivalent to rounding to the next 0.05 in the original.

Comment: @Sam Consider the set of floats between two consecutive integers, eg 0 and 1: 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, ..., 9.5. There are twenty elements. So, multiply the current number by 20, take the ceiling, then divide it by 20. http://jsfiddle.net/Wcjau/1/. @ Arth: Correct, I thought that he wanted to round up to the nearest number.

Comment: ahh, that's not really rounding to the nearest 0.05. should have checked the examples!

Comment: This returns a string - needs parseFloat like in other answers

Answer (score 19):

Rob's answer with my addition:

```
(Math.ceil(number*20 - 0.5)/20).toFixed(2)
```

Otherwise it always rounds up to the nearest 0.05.

** UPDATE **

Sorry has been pointed out this is not what the orig poster wanted.

Comment: I upvoted your comment, but then I realised that the OP asked to round up (see question's title).

Comment: This might not be what the OP asked for but it's exactly what I needed. You're missing a parentheses at the beginning of your answer. It should be `(Math.ceil(_amount*20 - 0.5)/20).toFixed(2)` (I fixed it).

Comment: @usama, I think I actually prefer @marksyzm's answer here for rounding. Basically there are 20 points, 0.05 apart, between two integers.. multiplying the value by 20 coverts the number into a system where each integer represents one of these points. Using an integer rounding method like `ceil`/`round` then allows you to round to the next/nearest point. Finally, dividing the result by the 20 converts you back to the original number system with a rounded value

Comment: @usama The additional `- 0.5` basically converts the `ceil` method to the `round` method, which is an unnecessary confusion.. much better to chose the right method!

Comment: @arth, your original addition to Rob's answer is more accurate regarding to banker rounding, as I had tested with MBS Online @ http://www9.health.gov.au/mbs/ready_reckoner.cfm?item_num=60, while you need a banker rounding function first @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108986/gaussian-bankers-rounding-in-javascript

Comment: This may be a local preference. The above answer will round 0.025 down to 0.00

If you are looking to round up at the mid-points
Math.floor(number*20 + 0.5)/20)

Answer (score 12):

I would go for the standard of actually dividing by the number you're factoring it to, and rounding that and multiplying it back again after. That seems to be a proper working method which you can use with any number and maintain the mental image of what you are trying to achieve.

```
var val = 26.14,
    factor = 0.05;

val = Math.round(val / factor) * factor;
```

This will work for tens, hundreds or any number. If you are specifically rounding to the higher number then use `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.round`.

Another method specifically for rounding just to 1 or more decimal places (rather than half a place) is the following:

```
Number(Number(1.5454545).toFixed(1));
```

It creates a fixed number string and then turns it into a real `Number`.

Answer (score 3):

I would write a function that does it for you by

- move the decimal over two places (multiply by 100)
- then mod (`%`) that `inflatedNumber` by 5 and get the remainder
- subtract the `remainder` from 5 so that you know what the 'gap'(`ceilGap`) is between your number and the next closest .05
- finally, divide your `inflatedNumber` by 100 so that it goes back to your original float, and voila, your num will be rounded up to the nearest .05.

  ```
  function calcNearestPointZeroFive(num){
      var inflatedNumber = num*100,
          remainder     = inflatedNumber % 5;
          ceilGap       = 5 - remainder

      return (inflatedNumber + ceilGap)/100
  }
  ```

If you want to leave numbers like 5.50 untouched you can always add this checker:

```
if (remainder===0){
    return num
} else {
    var ceilGap  = 5 - remainder
    return (inflatedNumber + ceilGap)/100
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put -1 to round half down and after that multiply by -1 like the example down bellow.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

  function roundNumber(number, precision, isDown) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
    var tempNumber = number * factor;
    var roundedTempNumber = 0;
    if (isDown) {
      tempNumber = -tempNumber;
      roundedTempNumber = Math.round(tempNumber) * -1;
    } else {
      roundedTempNumber = Math.round(tempNumber);
    }
    return roundedTempNumber / factor;
  }
</script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <p>Round number 1.25 down: <script>document.write(roundNumber(1.25, 1, true));</script>
  </p>
  <p>Round number 1.25 up: <script>document.write(roundNumber(1.25, 1, false));</script></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this function in my project, successfully:

```
roundToNearestFiveCents( number: any ) {
    return parseFloat((Math.round(number / 0.05) * 0.05).toFixed(2));
}
```

Might be of use to someone wanting to simply round to the nearest 5 cents on their monetary results, keeps the result a number, so if you perform addition on it further it won't result in string concatenation; also doesn't unnecessarily round up as a few of the other answers pointed out. Also limits it to two decimals, which is customary with finance.

Answer (score 1):

My solution and test:

```
let round = function(number, precision = 2, rounding = 0.05) {
  let multiply = 1 / rounding;

  return parseFloat((Math.round(number * multiply) / multiply)).toFixed(precision);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/maciejSzewczyk/7r1tvhdk/40/

Answer (score 1):

Even though the OP is not explicit about banker rounding, rounding up to the nearest $0.05 (5 cents) should be compatible with banker rounding. What suggested by Arth is more accurate than the accepted answer by Rob W.

`(Math.ceil(number*20 - 0.5)/20).toFixed(2)`

With banker rounding, you need a basic banker rounding function as suggested at [Gaussian/banker's rounding in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108986/gaussian-bankers-rounding-in-javascript), and I rewrite in TypeScript:

```js
    static bankerRound(num: number, decimalPlaces?: number) {
        const d = decimalPlaces || 0;
        const m = Math.pow(10, d);
        const n = +(d ? num * m : num).toFixed(8);
        const i = Math.floor(n), f = n - i;
        const e = 1e-8;
        const r = (f > 0.5 - e && f < 0.5 + e) ?
            ((i % 2 === 0) ? i : i + 1) : Math.round(n);
        return d ? r / m : r;
    }

    static roundTo5cents(num: number) {
        const r = bankerRound(Math.ceil(num * 20 - 0.5) / 20, 2);
        return r;
    }
```

The correctness of this algorithm could be verified through MBS Online, e.g. http://www9.health.gov.au/mbs/ready_reckoner.cfm?item_num=60