# How can I round a decimal up to the nth decimal?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

In JavaScript, I would like to round a given number (x) up based on another decimal (y). For example:

```
x = 8.6333
y = 0.5
result = 9

x = 8.6333
y = 0.2
result = 8.8

x = 8.6333
y = 0.1
result = 8.7
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gaussian/Banker's Rounding in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108986/gaussian-bankers-rounding-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide x by the y. Round that up, and multiply by y again.

```
var answer = Math.ceil(x/y)*y;
```

Comment: Great! A friend of mine just provided the same answer and it makes sense now! Thank you

Comment: Mathematically, that should work. But in "real life", it might not. For an explanation, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/