# Javascript rounding fails on 77.475 and 67.475

Tags: javascript, math, rounding, rounding-error

Using this code (https://jsfiddle.net/d5pjr60g/):

```
var num = 67.475;
var round = (Math.round( num * 100 ) / 100).toFixed(2);
alert(round);
```

The numbers 67.475 and 77.475 return 67.47 and 77.47 respectively. However, if you change any other number, it rounds "correctly". 57.475 or 67.375 will return 57.48 and 67.38 respectively.

I get the same result if I use the basic `var round = num.toFixed(2);`

This occurs on every browser. How can I get it to round 77.475 to 77.48?

Comment: `toFixed` doesn't round the decimal, it just truncates it

Comment: [`67.475 * 100` = `6747.499999999999`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1048572)

Comment: I don't understand. why not just `num.toFixed(2)`? What's all the other multiplying/dividing/rounding for?

Comment: @SterlingArcher You'd think, but changing the `var round` line to `var round = num.toFixed(2);` does the rounding still. But remember, that I call `Math.Round` before I call `toFixed`

Comment: @Kousha Same result either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is an issue with the rounding scheme, it could be using [banker's rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).  This solution handles it.
[Gaussian/banker's rounding in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108986/gaussian-bankers-rounding-in-javascript)

Comment: Had the same issue in a different programming language a couple days back. :)