# Equivalnet of C# or Python even rounding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, c#

There is a discrepancy between how C# or Python rounds a decimal number and how Javascript handles it. I've already found this answer [banker-rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108986/gaussian-bankers-rounding-in-javascript#comment135873096_49080858), but this solution does not work in my case and causes different results between server and client.

Suppose I have a variable `number` that its value is from `1.36500000000001` to `1.36500000000009`.

In C#:

```cs
// 1.36500000000001m

Math.Round(decimal_number, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) 
// 1.37
```

In Python:

```py
Decimal(str(number)).quantize(Decimal('0.01')), ROUND_HALF_EVEN))
# 1.37
```

But in Javascript:
based on different functions of [banker-rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108986/gaussian-bankers-rounding-in-javascript#comment135873096_49080858)

```js
function bankersRound(n, d=2) {
    var x = n * Math.pow(10, d);
    var r = Math.round(x);
    var br = Math.abs(x) % 1 === 0.5 ? (r % 2 === 0 ? r : r-1) : r;
    return br / Math.pow(10, d);
}
bankersRound(number, 2)
// 1.36
```

Has the community found a solution for Javascript? Is there any other implementation in Javascript?

Comment: Just FYI, the sample numbers you have provided are NOT triggering "banker's rounding".  "Banker's rounding" rounds 1.365 to 1.36.  Also, your code works perfectly for me.  I'll show an example below.

Comment: What about rounding this number 4394.355 with 2 decimal places? Python result is 4394.36, but Javascript is 4394.35. I would like to hear the community's insights.

Comment: That's the pain of working with floating point numbers.  When you do 4394.355 x 100, the result is 439435.49999999994, so `Math.round` rounds down.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us the sample numbers you were using, but if I put in your example, the code works exactly as expected:

```
function bankersRound(n, d=2) {
    var x = n * Math.pow(10, d);
    var r = Math.round(x);
    var br = Math.abs(x) % 1 === 0.5 ? (r % 2 === 0 ? r : r-1) : r;
    return br / Math.pow(10, d);
}
number = 1.36500000000001;
console.log(bankersRound(number, 2));
number = 1.365;
console.log(bankersRound(number, 2));
```

Output:

```
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ node x.js
1.37
1.36
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that I call the function directly ```console.log(bankersRound(1.36500000000001, 2));```. I should have passed it as a variable