# getting number only from 10.0 or 2

Tags: javascript, substring

I am trying to figure out how to go about detecting what browser is being used. Some report the version as being 10.0, 10, 4.6 or 5. How can i just get the whole number without any .x at the end (if it has one to begin with)?

I currently use this:

```
version = version.substring(0,3);
```

Which works if its a whole number but not if it has a period in them.

David

Comment: duplicated question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/596503/889678

Comment: Please don't do version detection, if you must serve different scripts for different browser, use [object detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html)

Answer (score 5):

What about something like...

```
var index = version.indexOf(".");
if(index != -1){
   version = version.substring(0, index);
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WjQp6/)

Answer (score 4):

convert it to a integer

```
versionInteger = parseInt(version, 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `parseInt()` with a radix of `10` to convert it to just the whole number part.

```
parseInt(10.5, 10);
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xFC9w/)

Answer (score 1):

```
version = version.split('.')[0];
```