# Use of bitwise OR operation in TypedArray.prototype.subarray() call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

The following code is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/encodeInto under heading "Encode Into A Specific Position".

```js
var encoder = new TextEncoder;
function encodeIntoAtPosition(string, u8array, position) {
    return encoder.encodeInto(string, position ? u8array.subarray(position|0) : u8array);
}

var u8array = new Uint8Array(8);
encodeIntoAtPosition("hello", u8array, 2);
console.log( "" + u8array.join() ); // 0,0,104,101,108,108,111,0
```

In `encodeIntoAPosition`, what is the reason for `position|0`?

Here are some results for bitwise OR operations.

```js
console.info([ 2|0, 2.5|0, 'z'|0, 'abc'|0, -2|0, -2.5|0 ]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: It coerces it to a number and truncates it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using bitwise OR in javascript to convert to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695504/using-bitwise-or-in-javascript-to-convert-to-integer)

Comment: @jdaz I'll have a read at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596467/how-do-i-convert-a-float-number-to-a-whole-number-in-javascript thx

Comment: @hev1 exactly. thx