# Total fields and add 2 decimal places only if fields have decimals?

Tags: jquery, decimal-point, cumulative-sum

Currently, I have the function:

```
function TotalAmount(field, container) {
    var total = 0;
    field.each(function () {
        total += $(this).val() * 1;
    });
    container.val(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Example(1): 
55.00 + 50.00 = 105.00 (this is correct)

Example (2): 
This currently returns: 
55 + 50 = 105.00

I need it to return 105 instead.

How do I change my functionality to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a float to an int in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596467/how-do-i-convert-a-float-to-an-int-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function TotalAmount(field, container) {
    var total = 0;
    field.each(function () {
        total += $(this).val() * 1;
    });
    container.val(total == parseInt(total) ? total : total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Rm5E2/)

Comment: getting no decimal places for all conditions.

Comment: for fiedl1: 1.00, field2: 1.00 and field3: 1.00, I get 3 instead of 3.00

Comment: @Chaka that is what you wanted right? `55 + 50 = 105` not `105.00`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 container.val(total == parseInt(total) ? total : total.toFixed(2));
```

[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: getting no decimal places for all conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Using modulous operator can solve ur issue:

```
If (total % 1 != 0)
return total
else 
return total / 100
```