# Writing an array in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to learn javascript, so I decided to code a script in Google Apss Script to list all emails with attachment. Until now, I have this code:

```
function listaAnexos() {
  // var doc = DocumentApp.create('Relatório do Gmail V2');
  var plan = SpreadsheetApp.create('Relatorio Gmail');
  var conversas = GmailApp.search('has:attachment', 0, 10)
  var tamfinal = 0;
  if (conversas.length > 0) {
    var tam = 0
    var emails = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(conversas);
    var cont = 0;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < emails.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < emails[i].length; j++) {
        var anexos = emails[i][j].getAttachments();
        for (var k = 0; k < anexos.length; k++) {
          var tam = tam + anexos[k].getSize();
        }
      }
      var msginicial = conversas[i].getMessages()[0];
      if (tam > 0) {
        val = [i,  msginicial.getSubject(), tam];
        planRange = plan.getRange('A1:C1');
        planRange.setValue(val);
        // doc.getBody().appendParagraph('A conversa "' + msginicial.getSubject() + '" possui ' + tam + 'bytes em anexos.');
      }
      var tamfinal = tamfinal + tam;
      var tam = 0;
    }
  }
}
listaAnexos();
```

It works, but with 2 problems:

1) It writes the three `val` values at `A1`, `B1` and `C1`. But I want to write `i` in `A1`, `msginicial.getSubject()` in `B1` and `tam` in `C1`.

2) How can I change the range interactively? Write the first email in `A1:C1`, the second in `A2:C2` ...

I know that are 2 very basic questions, but didn't found on google :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1: Make sure you use the right method for the range. You've used [`Range.setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue%28Object%29) which accepts a `value` as input, and modifies the content of the range using that one value. You should have used [`Range.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues%28Object%29), which expects an array and modifies a range of the same dimensions as the array. (The array must be a two-dimensional array, even if you're only touching one row.)

```
    val = [[i,  msginicial.getSubject(), tam]];
    planRange = plan.getRange('A1:C1');
    planRange.setValues(val);
```

Problem 2: (I assume you mean 'programmatically' or 'automatically', not 'interactively'.) You can either use row and column numbers in a loop say, with [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29), or build the range string using javascript string methods.

Comment: Problema 1 is ok. I changed `planRange = plan.getRange('A1:C1');` by `planRange = plan.getRange(1, 1, 3, 3);`, but now I'm getting tihs error message: `Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number). (line 20, file "Code")`. I tried convert the numbers to integer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596467/how-do-i-convert-a-float-to-an-int-in-javascript), but none of the solutions works. Any idea?