# How to round a floating value to its closest integer in Jquery

Tags: jquery, floating-point, int, rounding

I want to round both `130.68`(greater than or equals 130.5) and `131.32`(less than 131.5) values to `131`.

Comment: [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a number to an integer in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596467/how-do-i-convert-a-number-to-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```
Math.round(130.68); // return 131
Math.round(131.32); // return 131
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ZFG7d/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), In example below both statement will alert `131`

```
alert(Math.round(130.68));
alert(Math.round(131.32));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nx4zH/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Math.round

```
num=130.68; 
Math.round(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this link:

[Use Math.round()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_round)