# convert a decimal to integer in KnockOut

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

```
var amount = vm.AMOUNT();
```

The Above statement is coming with decimal point, I need to convert this statement to Interger.(Without Decimal Point)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a float number to a whole number in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596467/how-do-i-convert-a-float-number-to-a-whole-number-in-javascript)

Comment: You could use the method provided in the previous link inside a _knockout extender_: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html Check out "Live Example 1"

Comment: Jamiec - I am asking this in knockout not in Jquery or Javascript.

Comment: @user3297291 it doesn't say about float to interger. i have already seen that website and i have tried too. it is not working

Comment: You're using Knockout so you're using Javascript.  The link provided by @Jamiec provides a solution.  If you don't feel that will work for you, please show example code of what isn't working and [what you've already tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Knockout *is* javascript.

Answer (score 4):

From your comments I get the impression that linking to previous answers to similar questions might not help you out. So, for the sake of clarity:

**Original question**:

> I need to convert this statement to Interger [sic]

Javascript doesn't have a distinction between integers and floats; there's only `Number` ([read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number))

There are many ways to remove a decimal from a number. E.g.: you can use `Math.round()`, `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()` (if you want to go from *n* to *0* decimals).

```
var amount = vm.AMOUNT();
var roundedAmount = Math.round(amount); // As close as you'll get to an 'Integer'
```

**Comment #1**:

> I am asking this in knockout not in Jquery or Javascript

jQuery and knockout are javascript libraries. Functions such as `Math.round` are in the javascript spec and can be used no matter what libraries you're including.

**Comment #2**:

> > You could use the method provided in the previous link inside a knockout extender: knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html Check out "Live Example 1" – me
>
> it doesn't say about float to interger – you

I was trying to point you towards a solution that matches a way of coding that works well with knockout.

```
var amount = vm.AMOUNT();
```

To me, it seems that `vm.AMOUNT` is an observable that is set with values you don't want (i.e.: there's too many decimals).

If you want to control the types of values that your observable can contain, you can use an `extender`. This enables you to convert any value that is used to set `AMOUNT`'s value. If you *do* need both the decimal value as well as the rounded value, here's another approach:

```
var roundedAmount = ko.computed(function() {
    return Math.round(vm.AMOUNT());
});

vm.AMOUNT(12.34);

console.log(roundedAmount()); // Logs: 12
```