# How to convert the result of an array to Int?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building an app with Ionic and Firebase. I am having numbers with decimals sometimes and I would like to truncate them as integer.

Here is my code :

```
var visitMaster = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

        $timeout(function(){

          var visitRef = firebase.database().ref('/business/' + myId + '/visits/');

          // LAST HOUR
          visitRef.orderByChild("visit").startAt(nowMinusOne).endAt(now).once("value", function(snapshot) {
          var visitOneHour = (snapshot.numChildren() / 2);
          if (visitOneHour === ""){
          visitMaster.splice(6, 1, 0);
        } else {
          visitMaster.splice(6, 1, visitOneHour);
        }
          });
```

How to render the numbers in my **visitMaster** as **int** ?

**UPDATE** : each value of the array is supposed to go in a chart (bar) and so I display it that way :

```
//WE PUT IT IN THE CHART:
        $scope.labels = ["H-6", "H-5", "H-4", "H-3", "H-2", "H-1", "Now"];
        $scope.data = [
          visitMaster,

        ];
```

I would like that each value be an integer (most of them are x.5)

Comment: [A question of how to convert decimals to integers has been answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596467/how-do-i-convert-a-float-number-to-a-whole-number-in-javascript)

Comment: vistMaster.map(Number) maybe?

Comment: Are you trying to sum the total value from the array?

Comment: Hello, I added an update to my question, maybe it will be clearer ? Thank you in advance

Comment: @FrenchyNYC - I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to sum the value of `visitMaster` into a single integer value, you can do the following:

For ES5.

```
var total = visitMaster.reduce(function (total, visit) {
    return total + visit;
}, 0);
```

Or if using ES6.

```
let total = visitMaster.reduce((total, visit) => total + visit, 0);
```

And then to convert to an integer, I'd suggest using `Math.ceil`, which will round the value up to the next whole number.

```
total = Math.ceil(total);
```

**Update**
To just convert each value in your array to an integer, just use the `Array.prototype.map` function. Thanks to @Barmar for correction.

```
visitMaster = visitMaster.map(function (value) {
    return Math.floor(value); // or Math.ceil(value);
});
```

Comment: "sometimes and I would like to truncate them as integer." that's `parseInt`, not `Math.ciel`

Comment: Hello, I added an update to my question, maybe it will be clearer ? Thank you in advance

Comment: @CoryDanielson I was suggesting `Math.ceil` over `parseInt`, because it looks like the values are visit durations. So where `parseInt` will round down, this wouldn't necessary show the time required for a visit, whereas rounding up using `Math.ceil` would.

Comment: `Math.floor()` is the proper function for rounding down. `parseInt()` is for parsing strings containing integers. It will work for this because it first converts the number to a string and then parses it, but `Math.floor()` is simpler because it doesn't have to do any conversion.

Answer (score 1):

use the function `Math.floor()` to truncate a floating point number to its integer part. And use `Array.prototype.map` to process the entire array,.

```js
visitMaster = [1, 1.5, 2.1, 2.8, 111.345];
visitMaster = visitMaster.map(Math.floor);
console.log(visitMaster);
```