# What's wrong with my program? It is always returning "not found"

Tags: javascript

Check out my problem at:
 https://github.com/harishsambasivam/SearchingAlgorithms/blob/master/BinarySearch-RecursiveMethod.js

```js
function BinarySearch(low, high, key, arr) {
  if (low > high) return 'Not Found';
  if (low === high) {
    if (arr[low] === key) return "Found";
    else return "Not found";
  } else {
    var mid = Math.abs((low + high) / 2);
    if (arr[mid] === key) return "Found";
    else if (arr[mid] > key) return BinarySearch(low, mid - 1,
      key, arr);
    else return BinarySearch(mid + 1, high, key, arr);
  }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
console.log(BinarySearch(0, 7, 5, arr));
```

I expected both "found" and "not found", but only "not found" is being returned.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the main problem is from your mid value calculus.

`console.log(Math.abs((0 + 7) / 2)) //==> 3.5`

And for the next iteration the value will be /w decimals. You can fix that first.

You can fix that by: 
`Math.trunc((min + high) / 2);`

Comment: Not much sense in using an ES6 math function when an ES1 function would suffice.

Comment: I think both are okay. I think we  need to drive adoption of ES6 and get browsers to improve their implementations rather than resorting to old features.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `Math.abs` when you should be using `Math.floor`, and that is why it's not working. Using `Math.abs` is pointless here since `low` and `high` are always nonnegative.

```js
function BinarySearch(low, high, key, arr) {
  if (low > high) return 'Not Found';
  if (low === high) {
    if (arr[low] === key) return "Found";
    else return "Not found";
  } else {
    var mid = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    if (arr[mid] === key) return "Found";
    else if (arr[mid] > key) return BinarySearch(low, mid - 1,
      key, arr);
    else return BinarySearch(mid + 1, high, key, arr);
  }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
console.log(BinarySearch(0, 7, 5, arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use other Math functions instead of `Math.floor` by refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/596503/6517783

```js
function BinarySearch(low, high, key, arr) {
  if (low > high) return 'Not Found';
  if (low === high) {
    if (arr[low] === key) return "Found";
    else return "Not found";
  } else {
    var mid = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    if (arr[mid] === key) return "Found";
    else if (arr[mid] > key) return BinarySearch(low, mid - 1,
      key, arr);
    else return BinarySearch(mid + 1, high, key, arr);
  }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
console.log(BinarySearch(0, 7, 5, arr));
```

Comment: Why are you using `Math.abs` and `Math.floor` ?

Comment: For convert float value to integer. Because in next statement value is using as array index

Comment: Why do you need `Math.abs` for that ?

Comment: `Math.abs` will use to convert negative value to positive

Comment: But the values well never be negative in this case.

Comment: Yes, the solution is not only for single selected values. In question he is asking that his program always return "Not Found" i don't think his mean to say for single value. He must be tried with many different values and he gives a sample in snippet

Answer (score 0):

Here in mid value, you will get value in decimals which cannot select any arr[mid] element. So, for that, you can change the `math.abs` to `math.floor`/ `math.ceil` as per your requirement.