# Comparing element dimensions (float) with mouse coordinates (int)

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I have a `<div>` on a webpage with the following dimensions:

[image]

Using Javascript/jQuery I get the following position and dimensions of that element:

```
$elem.offset()
{top: 1434.4791564941406, left: 32.222225189208984}
$elem.outerWidth()
930
$elem.outerHeight()
536.788
```

It seems to me that a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) contains `clientX` and `clientY` (or `pageX`, `pageY`) coordinates in [`"number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Description) type.

**Question:** Why is it that a [`onmouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) event fires with a `clientX` value of `31` or `32` (depending on how quickly I move the mouse), both of which should be outside of the element’s border box.

**Question:** [Converting floats to integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596467/how-do-i-convert-a-float-number-to-a-whole-number-in-javascript) probably isn’t a good idea because of rounding. So, how do I go about checking the border box here: convert the mouse coordinates to floats? Meaning, that a `(1434, 32)` mouse coordinate is *just* outside whereas `(1435, 33)` is barely inside of the bounding box?

Comment: `clientX` value is w.r.t the entire client area of the application (browser), see 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX

Comment: @nivendha, well [`pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) has the same value… 

Comment: hope this clarifies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y

Comment: @nivendha, that still doesn’t answer the question: how can I correlate mouse coordinates to the border box of the element.