# Always hide .00 decimal number

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to format my decimal numbers to display 2 decimal places but .00 will always hide.

example

```
value      expect     return     
------     -------    ------
1.00       1           1.00
1          1           1.00
1.6        1.60        1.60
1.451      1.45        1.45
```

My Code

```
Vue.filter("currency", value => {
    return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
});
```

Comment: `parseFloat(value).toFixed(2).replace(".00","")`

Comment: num => num % 1 !== 0 ? parseFloat(num).toFixed(2) : num

Comment: @Ouroborus It works. Thank You.

Comment: @nosnart you could have posted this as an answer, I too went for the same approach, the same time you posted the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `.00` from the end if it exists:

```
 return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2).replace(/\.00$/, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the `toFixed` INTO the `parseFloat` like this:

```js
Vue.filter("currency", value => {
    return parseFloat(value.toFixed(2))
});
```

> toFixed will round/pad the number to a specific length, but also convert it to a string. Converting that back to a numeric type will not only make the number safer to use arithmetically, but also automatically drop any trailing 0's.

Reference: https://newbedev.com/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number

**Update**

This solution doesn't consider the case: 1.6 -> 1.60 (check jsfiddle in the comment)

Comment: This wont work, this will only round the number to maximum of 2 decimal places. Wont work with inputs with one decimal place. Works only with no or more than 2 decimal places Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ku2ey76p/

Comment: Good point - thanks for clarification. Didn't consider that case.

Comment: Please fix that issue, so that I can revert the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the number is wholenumber by checking the reminder on division with 1

```js
Vue.filter("currency", value => {
    return parseFloat(value) % 1 === 0 ? parseFloat(value).toString() : parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the number converted to Integer has same value. return accordingly.
[change the parseint according to your requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596467/how-do-i-convert-a-float-number-to-a-whole-number-in-javascript)

```
Vue.filter("currency", (value )=>{
    if(value === parseInt(value )){return value}
    else {return parseFloat(value ).toFixed(2)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regex version:

```js
Intl.NumberFormat('en', { style:'currency', currency:'usd' }).format(num).replace(/\.?0*$/, '');
// $12.00  ->  $12
// $12.4   ->  $12.4
// $12.44  ->  $12.44
// $12.04  ->  $12.04
```